# MSDN Statement Completion Special Characters

Tags: c#, autocomplete, special-characters, intellisense, msdn

I've recently followed the Walkthrough on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx and successfully managed to get it going with the included list whereby I am able to add simple string values to get it to complete whatever I type that is in the string.

```
 void ICompletionSource.AugmentCompletionSession(ICompletionSession session, IList<CompletionSet> completionSets)
    {
        List<string> strList = new List<string>();

                    strList.Add("addition_test");
                    strList.Add("adaptation");
                    strList.Add("subtraction");
        m_compList = new List<Completion>();
        foreach (string str in strList)
            m_compList.Add(new Completion(str, str, str, null, null));
```

As shown I have the standard strings shown, "addition_test","adaptation"
 and "subtraction". They all work.

However I would want to know if it is possible for me to put special characters infront of it. Such as

- strList.Add("#adapt");
- strList.Add("?adapt_nation");
- strList.Add("/#@adapt_entity");

I am unable to get it to display the statement with special characters infront, I was wondering if there was a way to do it and how to?

Cheers

Comment: Try putting a `@` symbol before the strings, such as `strList.Add(@"#adapt");`, etc. That symbol forces the string to be verbatim, and not escaped by default. [2.4.4.5 String literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @keyurPatel Hi! I've tried to do that and yes, it went through and added the "@" sign into the list but it does not show up in the completion. For E.g. when I type "ad", "addition" would show and I would be able to select it using space/enter/selecting it. 

With the @ infront of the string, I'm unable to get a completion for e.g. "@ad" does not give me the option to finish up "@addition"

Comment: Well that seems more to do with how you code the 'autocorrect' feature rather than how c# is storing the strings.

Comment: Do you by any chance know how, looking at the  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx because I do not know where to start modifying the code. Thank you.

Comment: I have never come across this, so I can only speculate, but try changing `&& char.IsLetterOrDigit(typedChar)` to `&& (char.IsLetterOrDigit(typedChar) || char.IsPunctuation(typedChar))` in the `public int Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Answer By @Keyur PATEL

**I have never come across this, so I can only speculate, but try changing**

```
&& char.IsLetterOrDigit(typedChar)
```

**to**

```
&& (char.IsLetterOrDigit(typedChar) || char.IsPunctuation(typedChar))
```

**in the**

```
public int Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID, uint nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) function.
```